# Sync audio and text together

Tags: iphone, ios6

Is there some way to synchronize audio with text. Like audio file is playing and first line is displayed in textview now when audiofile reaches to second line text in textview should change itself to second line. I m unable to find solution for this. If someone can help me with this. Will appreciate so much for help.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you need is some kind of Lyric APP. Even though you haven't mentioned Music once in your question, lyrics can be used for a platform of things such as music, audio books, story's and presentations.

There are many on the iPhone App Database, but your not restricted in making the lyric file for your audio file on the iPhone you could use some PC/Mac software such as http://www.evillabs.sk/evillyrics/ and then use that on your iPhone.

Just a quick search for the Iphone I found http://lyricsapp.net/ which you should check out, if your creating the lyrics in Windows then just ensure that the lyric app on the iphone reads the lyric format of the file.